# Velocity.js leaving text artefacts on fade out

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I am struggling to see why this leaves slight text fragments at the top of where an element has  had the HTML replaced and then faded back in. This is the code:

```
$('.current-station-services li').on('click', function() {

    $(this).find('.status').velocity({
        opacity: 0
    },{
        duration: 100,
        complete: function() {
            $(this).html(data.test);
            $(this).velocity({
                opacity: 1
            })
        }
    });

});
```

Here is an image also of the output (artefact above the 'yo!'):

[image]

Comment: could you put this together in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser issue, not Velocity. Feel free to submit a bug report to webkit/gecko.